# Smooth line on histograms in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, probability-density

I want to make a smooth line over histograms. So far I have tried all the smooth functions but I am not able to get the result.

For the histograms I am using:

```
plot "file.scatter" u (hist($2,width)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes notitle
```

and the result is:[image: this]

But when I ask gnuplot to draw a smooth line over these:

```
plot "file.scatter" u (hist($2,width)):(1.0) smooth freq w l notitle
```

I get: 
[image: this]

I want the line plot to look smooth like a probability density function(of course the values will have to be normalized).

Any clues experts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do a convolution, if you have a recent version of gnuplot (>=5.1) you can plot with `kdensity`

```
plot $DATA smooth kdensity [bandwidth n] with boxes
```

Keep in mind that recent versions of gnuplot can also do the binning for the histogram with the `bins` feature.